# Version Control System similar to Bazaar needed for CentOS 4.8 dedicated hosting server

Tags: version, version-control

I have recently had to have our dedicated server rebuilt as core system files were deleted. But that's another story...

Before the rebuild, we were merging, branching, and committing changes to a number of different projects with Bazaar. Now it seems that the hosting company has rebuilt the server at CentOs 4.8 rather than 5.0, which I guess it was before. According to the support staff, Bazaar is not compatible with the new OS.

The support staff have said:

> I have installed all of the Bazaar
>   Dependencies, however the missing
>   dependencies for example;
>
> - Missing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by
>     package bzr
>
> Is for a higher version of CentOS.

My question is. Is this entirely true and is there any way to get Bazaar working on Centos 4.8?

If not, are there any other version control systems similar to Bazaar?

Below is the log for the attempted installation of Bazaar.

```
Error: Missing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by package bzr
Error: Missing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 is needed by package bzr
Error: Missing Dependency: rtld(GNU_HASH) is needed by package bzr
Error: Missing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6 is needed by package python-pycurl
Error: Missing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 is needed by package python-paramiko
Error: Missing Dependency: rtld(GNU_HASH) is needed by package python-pycurl
Error: Missing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 is needed by package python-pycurl
Error: Missing Dependency: libssl.so.6 is needed by package python-pycurl
Error: Missing Dependency: rtld(GNU_HASH) is needed by package python-crypto
Error: Missing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by package python-crypto
Error: Missing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 is needed by package python-crypto
Error: Missing Dependency: python-abi = 2.4 is needed by package python-crypto
```

Comment: @Brendan personally I would tell your Host that CentOS 4.8 is not an option and you must have 5.0, generally speaking it's a giant no no for a host to change your version on you like that, esp if you have CLI access which usually means you're dedicated or VPS, they need to put you on the proper version. Outside of that would Mercurial or Git serve  your purposes?

Comment: I agree with xenoterracide. Ask to go back to the previous version or change hosting. This version of CentOS is so old they won't make bazaar work without a lot of hack and slash.

Comment: Support for RHEL4 (and thus CentOS 4) will stop in Q1 of 2012. That seems a long time but it is not. Move to RHEL5 / CentOS5 and save yourself some pain in the not-too-distant future.

Comment: You might consider changing hosting companies anyway.  A hosting company that will arbitrarily switch to an older OS version that will be out of support in a year and a half doesn't sound reliable to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* need to stay on RHEL4 / CentOS4 (think about this, read my comment to your original post), you can find RPM's for at least [git](http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/4/SRPMS/git-1.5.4.7-3.el4.src.rpm) and [mercurial](http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/4/SRPMS/mercurial-1.2-2.el4.1.src.rpm) in [EPEL for RHEL4](http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/4/). Both are comparable to bazaar, but lack the Launchpad integration that (I think) Bazaar has.

Answer (score 1):

You could install it from sources. I has quite a few dependencies and apparently some parts seem to be written in C though. It seems however not especially complicated. There is a fairly detailed description here:

http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/SourceDownloads